# Continuum removal algorithm in python

Tags: python, spectral-method, special-functions

I'm using python 2.7 (on jupyter notebook, win10 64 bit) to perform my analysis. I need to perform continuum removal (CR) on a reflectance spectrum data. I need it to be as described [here][1].

EDITED:

I used the following code to perform CR on a reflectance spectrum:

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

i = Xdata.iloc[15,:] #get the data from a pandas df
ii = i.tolist()
mat = np.column_stack((wavelenght_list,ii))
hull = ConvexHull(mat)
plt.plot(mat[:,0], mat[:,1], 'o')
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(mat[simplex, 0], mat[simplex, 1], 'k-')
```

The result I get is:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I have 3 questions about it:

1. Why it did not capture the local maxima at 550?
2. How can I remove the baseline of the convelHull (the black curve)?
3. How can I divide my spectrum by the "upper" conveHull in order to get CR spectrum?
   [1]: http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/ContinuumRemoval.html
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5qah.jpg

**UPDATE:**
Thanks you all for your help-  I found a more suitable module for my needs to perform the continuum removal algorithm: `spectro` in `pysptools`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to fit a convex hull to the data (e.g., reflectance as a function of the wavelength).  The SciPy packages has the tool you need, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html.

After that you will need to subtract the convex hull value from the actual value after interpolation along the convex hull, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html.

Comment: hi, thanks, I still did not get the result I was aiming for. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: At this point you will have to select the points on the convex hull that are above your blue line and find the values of reflectance on that hull (say, $R_h$) corresponding to the wavelengths of the original data (suing interpolation).  If the original reflectance was $R$, then the quantity you want is $R/R_h$.  You can split the hull into two parts (upper and lower), based on the end points.

Comment: I understand what I'm suppose to do in order to get what I want, I use CR algorithm in ENVI software, but can you assist me in how to do it? I mean script-wise, how do I choose the appropriate pairs of data and interpolate? and, can I change a parameter so the ConvexHull will capture the local max in 550?

Comment: To get the local max. at 550 nm you will need to break the data up and create two hulls.  The convex hull (in your problem) is the convex polygon that surrounds all points. For an interpolation example, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html .  To locate the end points of the upper hull just write a loop and check.  It's straightforward to do that.